# Using Vim to find definition when navigation around /usr/include/files

Tags: c, vim, header-files

I found it was casual to navigate between header files when you want do something under linux. And when I want find a definition of something, for example, `struct sockaddr_storage`. What I am doing right now is `:!find /usr/include/ -type f | xargs grep " struct sockaddr "`. It's powerful, but unconvincing for me.

Does there exist an easier way to navigate around .h files like other IDEs, e.g.,VStudio, offer? ( almost C/CPP user am I ) ctags and cscope or tagbar are for project use, can they benefit me in this situation?

Comment: Yes, ctags and cscope can be run across files in /usr/include. If you have a recursive version and make a pass, ctags may generate close to 100 megs in tags, maybe more.  It'll be overwhelming, as you'll likely get a lot of multiples, but you'll be able to find just about anything.  If you get tired of the vim duplicate list selector, you may want to spend some time refining the file list passed to ctags.

Comment: FWIW, Vim has never been, is not, and will never be or pretend to be an IDE. You *have* to accept that reality if you want your transition from IDE to Vim to go smoothly. That said, Vim does *a lot* and a lot of its built-in features are designed with C in mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vim can follow include files and find symbols where they are defined. For that, it uses a number of options:

```
:help 'path'
:help 'include'
:help 'define'
```

The whole mechanism is described under `:help include-search`.

In your case, and assuming you have `#include <sys/socket.h>` in the current buffer, you would do:

```
:ijump sockaddr_storage
```

or:

```
:isplit sockaddr_storage
```

or:

```
:isp /socka
```

or press `[I` with the cursor on `sockaddr_storage`.

The default value of the `define` option for C is limited to `#define` but it can be expanded to include things like `struct`, `int`, etc.

```
:set define=^\\s*#*\\s*\\(define\\\|struct\\)
```

Which lets you do something like:

```
:dlist sockaddr_storage
```

The alternative is obviously to use a code indexer like [ctags](https://ctags.io/) (`:help ctags`), [gnu global](https://www.gnu.org/software/global/), or [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/) (`:help cscope`) to index both your project *and* `/usr/include/`.

Comment: Hi, fellow Stack Overflow fan, would you like to meet up at devoxx fr? I created a chatroom for us: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/109630/devoxx-fr

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a tag tool, such as [ctags](https://andrew.stwrt.ca/posts/vim-ctags/) or [gtags](https://www.gnu.org/software/global/globaldoc_toc.html#Vim-editor)